# Deny fast click login posts

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a PHP AJAX json login form that I built.
I already have function that if you have been over than 5 failed attempts, the login form will be blocked.

But how to deny fast login attemps that has not entered user or pass?

I mean here in stackoverflow's login system when you click fast on the login button, 70% of the posts to server are denied.

And I don't want to make delay between posts, just to deny posts before the other post has been finished.

So what is the best way to deny fast click login posts?

Comment: You could use a honeypot actually, or sleep function. Plus sessions wouldn't be a bad option neither.

Comment: sleep would be bad its will take times between faild attemps , which i dont want be heppen ..

Comment: well then use a honeypot even though they are used mostly against Spammers, it will work. Plus sessions/cookies.

Comment: Disable the login button or the login action until after you receive your response from first ajax call.

Comment: Just wonder how stackflaw handle this sitotaion , and how he deny 70% uncessery posts requests........

Comment: @asdasdasda Have a look at the last example on this page http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/271026-please-help-a-noob-simple-honeypot/ this is exactly what you need. And don't forget to put `session_start();` on top. And/or I can post an example that I made based on that which is what I presently use.

Comment: thanks its very close to what i needed :).

Comment: @asdasdasda You're welcome. Do you want me to post what I use for you to try it out?

Comment: If you can would be great idea , anyway i will have to make some updrades .. :)

Comment: @asdasdasda Ok, doing it now.

Comment: @asdasdasda Try my code and then click the Submit button as soon as you see the page, within one second. Then try it after 3-5 seconds and you will get a different result.

Comment: Thanks i will play with that :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following (example) method which works server-side, along with sessions to prevent people from clicking too fast.

The present code is set to 3 seconds minimum.

You can put the code you are using for successful post inside the `else` condition.

**Important:** If you are using multiple pages, then `session_start();` needs to be inside every page, for included files also.

Presently set to work inside ONE file, using `action=""`

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['start_time'] = time();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $current_time = time();

    if (!empty($_POST['start_time'])) {
        if (($current_time - $_POST['start_time']) < 3) { // 5 is number of seconds differential; change as you sit fit
            // someone/something has submitted this form in under 5 seconds from reaching the page
            // probably a bot

echo "Sorry, too fast";

exit;
        }

else {

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$fname = ucwords($fname);
echo "Thank you $fname";

}
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="start_time" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['start_time']; ?>"/>

    <!-- other form fields -->

<input type="text" name="fname">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deny posts before the previous one has been done

I would suggest storing a post status value in a session

so when a post is made this status will change to a value indicating it is busy

and if someone tries to post before it is done they will get a message from the server that that it is busy.

I am not sure how you are implementing this but this is more like pseudo code explaining this idea.

```
 <?
       if($_SESSION['busy'] == true){ 
         $_SESSION['busy'] = true; 
         //PHP POST HANDLER CODE HERE 
         $_SESSION['busy'] = false;
         //RETURN JSON FOR RESULT OF LOGIN ATTEMPT    
        }
       else
        {
          //RETURN JSON FOR BUSY STATUS
        }  

 ?>
```